# Make nav bar transparent when resting at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css, json, shopify, liquid

For my website, I would like to have my navigation bar background colour set to transparent while I'm at the very top of the page, and idol. However, when I scroll down I would want it to appear as white again. Although the background colour is transparent, the text / page labels will still be there. This is what it looks like so far:

[Nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9mV6.png)

I would like it to be similar to elgato's navigation bar where it is transparent on idol at the top of the page. This is the code for the CSS so far (it's also mixed with Liquid, a language on shopify).

```
/* section-header */
#shopify-section-header {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}

.shopify-section-header-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.shopify-section-header-hidden {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.shopify-section-header-hidden.menu-open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#shopify-section-header.animate {
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-out;
}

/* Main Header Layout */
.header-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(var(--color-background));
  
  
}

.header-wrapper--border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid rgba(var(--color-foreground), 0.08);
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'left-icon heading icons';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here ya go. You need to detect when the user scrolls to update the header styles

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the solid class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "solid" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("solid");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("solid");
  }
}
```

```css
body { background-color: gray; }

header {
height: 75px;
width: 100%;
position: sticky;
top: 20px;
transition: all 0.5s;
background-color: lightblue;
}

header.solid {
background-color: darkgray;
}

.tall {
width: 100%;
height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<header id="myHeader"><span>The Header</span></header>

<div class="tall">
<p>Tall DIV</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What page do I add the function? // Where do I put the function> I've only got things like index.json, header.liquid etc

Comment: Ah that is right you are using shopify. You can probably add it within the page where you are editing the HTML. You would want to put it in a script tag though.

<script>
-----JS Code Here------
</script>

Here is a forum from shopify on adding JS code https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussions/how-do-i-add-javascript-code-to-an-individual-page/td-p/400438

Comment: this actually worked! only problem is now that when the navigation bar is transparent on the top, since the image isn't part of the background of the nav, the navigation bar just sits as white when on top. How do I make it so that the nav bar overlaps the background image?

Comment: You probably have a couple options. You can add a background-color to the header element so it has a color that fades on scroll, or a background color to the entire body. Probably safer to do the header though. I updated my snippet for ya! There is also a change the body has margin that is giving the white space the header sits on.